# How to properly wait for WCF asynchrony

Tags: wcf, mvvm, asynchronous, wait, async-await

This is my first question on the boards.  I am writing my first enterprise-worthy Silverlight (5) application, using WCF and the MVVM pattern.  My problem is that I don't understand how to have the model class call a WCF service, and (here's the problem), **wait** for the results before returning them to the calling view model.

I looked at msdn for usage of the async and await keywords, but I was unsure what method needed to be marked as "async".  It seemed to me that the service's auto-generated Reference.cs file might need to be modified, but I have my doubts.  More fundametally, I am not even sure that I need to use async and await at all, becuase I assume it should work as I expect by virtue of using WCF.

Anyway, here is the model class I have.  I expect the return statement to be executed AFTER the completion of the WCF call, but that is not the case:

```
public class CRMModel
{
    ObservableCollection<CarrierInfo> carrierInfoCollection = new ObservableCollection<CarrierInfo>();

    public ObservableCollection<CarrierInfo> GetCarrierInformation()
    {
        var client = new CarrierRateService.CarrierRateServiceClient();
        client.GetCarrierInformationCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            var info = e.Result;
            carrierInfoCollection = info;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Just got the result set: " + carrierInfoCollection.Count);

        };

        client.GetCarrierInformationAsync();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("About to return with: " + carrierInfoCollection.Count);
        return carrierInfoCollection;
    }
}
```

The result, as you probably guessed, is:

About to return with: 0

Just got the result set: 3

Thanks a lot for your help!
Francis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions, Stpehen and Toni.  I was still struggling until I used the approach outlined in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/154736/Data-and-Command-Bindings-for-Silverlight-MVVM-App) whereby the VM passes a callback method to the model, which merely calls the WCF service with this method in tow.

When I had originally specified the logic in an anonymous function in the model, I ran into the timing problem with the asynchrony.

I come from a mainframe background, so this simple sort of thing in .NET is still novel to me. :)

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO!

First off, to enable `async` and `await` in Silverlight 5 you'll need to install the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async package](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) (currently in Beta).

Next, you need to address the fact that the WCF proxy generator did not produce `await`-compatible asynchronous methods. The easiest way to fix this is to check the appropriate box in the Visual Studio 2012 Add Service Reference dialog. I'm not 100% sure this'll work for Silverlight, though, so if it doesn't, you can [use `TaskCompletionSource` to create your own `async`-compatible wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178.aspx#EAP).

Here is the full example code:

```
public static Task<ObservableCollection<CarrierInfo>> GetCarrierInformationTaskAsync(this CarrierRateService.CarrierRateServiceClient @this)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ObservableCollection<CarrierInfo>>();

    @this.GetCarrierInformationCompleted += (s,e) =>
    {
        if (e.Error != null) tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
        else if (e.Cancelled) tcs.TrySetCanceled();
        else tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
    };
    @this.GetCarrierInformationAsync(url);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

You can now await it using the following code:

```
public ObservableCollection<CarrierInfo> GetCarrierInformation()
{
    var client = new CarrierRateService.CarrierRateServiceClient();
    carrierInfoCollection = await client.GetCarrierInformationTaskAsync();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Just got the result set: " + carrierInfoCollection.Count);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("About to return with: " + carrierInfoCollection.Count);
    return carrierInfoCollection;
}
```

Comment: Dang, really?  I guess I'm surprised that anything "special" is required to get this to work with WCF.  The option is disabled when generating a service client.  Oh well, thanks for your assistance...I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: PS - I should say the option is checked, though the checkbox is disabled.